# How can I change controller properties/values from outside?

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm doing my first Steps with ember.js, and have a little problem.

After submitting a form, a POST will be sent with jQuery (works fine). After that, the success function should change "val1" to "newVal". Unfortunately, I don't know how to realize this.

HTML:

```
<form {{action "submitAction" on="submit"}}>...</form>
```

JS:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    prop1: "val1",
    prop2: "val2",
    submitAction: function () {
        // here, this.set("prop1","newVal") works fine.
        $.ajax({
            //(...)
            type: "POST",
            success: function () {
                // but how can I set it here?
            },
            //(...)   
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is the ajax function returning?  You pass the result to the function.

Comment: For now, there isn't a url in $.ajax (still testing). The function is returning the complete html-code of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    prop1: "val1",
    prop2: "val2",
    submitAction: function () {
        // here, this.set("prop1","newVal") works fine.
        var $submit = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            //(...)
            type: "POST",
            success: function () {
                // but how can I set it here?
              $submit.set("prop1","newVal");
            },
            //(...)   
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Using  submit = this   instead of $(this) works fine.